# Html countdown timer not working on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Hi I am facing timer countdown problem in page reload, below is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.now();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      document.getElementById("clockdiv").className = "hidden-div";
      document.getElementById("timeIsNow").className = "visible-div";
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      return true;
    }

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var deadline = '2015-12-14T20:14:00+02:00';

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
                </script>
                <style>
        body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.hidden-div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.visible-div {
  visibility: visible;
}
#clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>

                <div id="clockdiv" class="visible-div">
                    <span class="days"></span> Days
                    <span class="hours"></span> Hours
                    <span class="minutes"></span> Minutes
                    <span class="seconds"></span> Seconds
                </div>
            </body>    
        </html>
```

when I reload my page the timer is setting to it is default time and it is displaying from setting time, I have few codes which come across online but I am unable to do this, so I am seeing some help in doing it. 
Thank you.

Comment: What behaviour do you *want*? What do you expect to happen when someone reloads the page? You're running **client-side** code here without any persistence.

Comment: @André Dion That was my first reaction as well, then I looked closely at the script. He has a hardcoded target date, you can compute difference to it on client side (target date - now on client). Since now is computed at runtime it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to compute the time until e set date in the future.

You have 3 issues in your code that prevent that:

1.Your html, that is accessed by your js is loaded AFTER the js. You are referencing divs that were not loaded (for example here var clock = document.getElementById(id);). This breaks your script.

2.The element referenced here does not exist: document.getElementById("timeIsNow").className = "visible-div";. This breaks your script.

3.The target date is in the past (var deadline = '2015-12-14T20:14:00+02:00';). This does not break the script, but it clears the timer (so obviously it will only tick twice).

4.In the code you posted there is no other thing preventing you to compute the time, and it will work after reload since the date is hardcoded. Any other issues regarding timezones, date refreshing etc. are not related to the posted code.

As a side note (don't take this the wrong way, I'm just trying to help and it is a personal opinion)... the code is tragic (the scope of functions, computing on client side, indent, etc.). And the method used for computing is questionable at best; I suggest a refactoring (but those are not related with the question, just some tips).

Answer (score -2):

This will helpful if you want to call on every second

```
function worldClockZone() {
           setTimeout("worldClockZone()", 1000)
}
window.onload = worldClockZone;
```

Comment: This is helpful, but is not an answer, I suggest posting as a comment.